# Testing the save functionality using Jasmine in angular 4 application

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to write a test using Jasmine for my angular 4 application. I need to test the Ok method my setting incorrect values. I have written the test partially but not sure how to validate the OK method using jasmine. So basically when the values are invalid the isMinValid function or the isMaxValid function will set the corresponding private variables _isMinValid and _isMaxValid to false.

I have written test for the functions alone but not sure how to test the Ok Method

```
     private _isMinValid: boolean = false;
      private _isMaxValid: boolean = false;
 public data: any;



     public show() {
        this.domicileId = this.data.domicile.id;
        this.domicile = this.data.domicile;
        this.domiciles = this.data.domiciles;
        this._selectedIndustries = this.data.selectedIndustries;
        this.domicileInfo = this.domicile.domicileInformation;
        this.amendAssumptions = this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.DOMICILES.AMENDASSUMPTIONS', { domicile: this.domicile.name });
        this.active = true;
      }

          public ok() {
            if (this._isMinValid && this._isMaxValid) {
              this.data.domicileId = this.domicileId;
              this.data.domicileInfo = this.domicileInfo;
              this.hide(true);
            }
          }

           isMinValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
            if (item_IDX === 0) {
              this._isMinValid = true;
              return true;
            }
            let previousItem = this.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[item_IDX - 1];
            if (+currentItem.minSize !== +previousItem.maxSize) {
               this._isMinValid = false;
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          }


          isMaxValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
            if (item_IDX === 0) {
              this._isMaxValid = true;
              return true;
            }

            if (+currentItem.maxSize <= +currentItem.minSize) {
              this._isMaxValid = false;
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          }


  Tests




describe('DomicileSelectionComponent', () => {
      let comp: DomicileSelectionComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<DomicileSelectionComponent>;

      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [
            TooltipModule.forRoot(),
            FormsModule,
            TranslateModule.forRoot({
              loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader }
            })
          ],
          providers: [
            { provide: BsModalRef, useClass: BsModalRefStub },
            { provide: BackendProxy.ReferenceProxy, useClass: ReferenceProxyStub },
            { provide: RunService, useValue: runServiceStub }
          ],
          declarations: [DomicileSelectionComponent, YesNoPipe, CLICK_INPUT_DIRECTIVE, ShortNumberFormatPipe]
        });
      });

      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DomicileSelectionComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        comp.domicileInfo =  domicileInformationDataResult.data;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });


          fit('should return false because the current item min value is not equal to the previous max value', () => {
            comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items = [{maxSize: 40000000 , minSize: 30000000 , values: [2 , 2]}];
            let isMin: boolean = comp.isMinValid(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items , 1);
            //expect(isMin).toBe(false);
            //expect(comp.ok()).toHaveBeenCalled();
          });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ok()` function seems pretty straightforward to test really. Its `if` block just checks two variables to see if they're true and then moves on. So to test that just set those variables and do the test:

```
describe('ok()', () => {
  it('should set variables and call "hide()" function', () => {
    spyOn(comp, 'hide');

    // first check to make sure that they aren't already set
    expect(comp.data.domicileId).toEqual(null);
    expect(comp.data.domicileInfo).toEqual(null);

    comp._isMinValid = true;
    comp._isMaxValid = true;
    comp.domicileId = 1;
    comp.domicileInfo = 'foo';
    comp.ok();

    expect(comp.data.domicileId).toEqual(1);
    expect(comp.data.domicileInfo).toEqual('foo');
    expect(comp.hide).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: I am getting error saying argument of type hide cannot be assigned to type comp and similarly foo is not assignable to type domicileInfo

Comment: Argument of type '"hide"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"domicileInfo" | "data" | "onClose" | "active" | "currentSelectedCurrency" | "domicileId" | "domi...'.

Comment: I think it was because the method hide was private. I have changed it to public

Comment: now i get error Cannot set property 'domicileId' of undefined

Comment: @Tom yes that would do it. How is this.data initialized?

Comment: I have updated the post. If you can see i have included the show method where the domicileId is initialized. The show method is the method that is part of an interface which is implemented by this component. It fires when the modal window loads

Comment: I have managed to initialize the domicileid. Now the issue is that inorder to access hide method, i need to make it public. I think it is not a good practice to make a member public just because it needs to be accessed outside the class. I would ideally need to provide valid , invalid data and test